# What is recommended method for mounting chandelier canopy that has 2 screws?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, brackets

I want to mount a chandelier canopy like this one to the ceiling.

[image: Canopy]

You'll notice the hole on the left and the hole on the right.

The way this assumingly is supposed to work is that you have the bracket which is screwed to the electrical box as shown:

[image: Bracket with screws for electrical box]

And once that bracket is screwed to the electrical box, you take the screws that came with the canopy and hang them down through the slots as follows:

[image: Bracket with all screws]

Then I assumed that you push the canopy up to the bracket, with the screws that are pointing down going through the two holes on the canopy:

[image: Bracket in canopy]

and as seen from the other side:

[image: Canopy with screws]

And then finally you screw these nice little trim pieces - little caps - onto the screw ends to finish it off.

[image: Canopy with trim piece]

The problem is that in any bracket the screws that hang down into the holes in the canopy are free floating in the slots.  So when I press the canopy onto the screws and try to screw on the caps there is nothing to hold the screws in place and I can never get the caps on.

I must be doing this wrong?

Comment: That hickey isn't for the cord.  Don't route it through there unless you have no choice.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no choice since the strain relief pieces forces the cord in a direction that would conflict with the bracket if I didn’t put the cord through the center hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you figure out the spacing of the bolts hanging down, you thread a nut on the bolts on the side of the bracket opposite the heads.

Cinch down the nuts, check the alignment. If okay, install the bracket and the bolts should stay put as you try to tighten the nut.

Comment: Why I didn’t think of this first will haunt me forever lol.

Comment: No, no. Simply lesson learned. The best of mechanics/electricians have the "of course!" moments.

Answer (score 2):

I believe  you have it upside down.

The floating screws in the slots attach the bracket to the box and the other screws are in threaded holes so you can adjust them up or down to give you the exact amount you need that sticks through the canopy.

Comment: I agree if the threaded holes align with the holes in the canopy. If not, you can use the slots if you use nuts to lock the bolts in place.

Comment: Initially I thought I might have it upside down but the screw I show pointing upwards are the proper size and pitch for the lighting box whereas the downward screws aren’t; and the holes don’t line up, and also the trim end caps only fit the screws I show that are going down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the quality or provenance of the unit, but it looks like they tossed in a random, generic mounting bracket.  It's possible the mounting bracket does not fit your ceiling (or *even the lamp*, if it's an imported cheapie from you-know-where, with attendant quality problems).

The right way to use that mounting bracket is to a) mount it to the ceiling box using the slots, unthreaded holes or hickey; then b) mount the lamp to the bracket, screw heads down, shank going into the threaded holes provided as part of the bracket. I'm not sure why they provided those nut caps, but it sounds like a "just in case".

Also, keep in mind that **not every junction box is chandelier rated**. A standard box is only rated for a light that weighs 4 pounds. As such, it may not have screws in the right place for a chandelier bracket.